# Conditional extremes of $f(x,y,z)$

Tags: analysis

There is a given function $f(x,y,z)=xe^{x+2y+3z}$ and the set $K={(x,y,z) | x,y,z \geq 0, x+2y+3z \leq 16}$ where I have to find all the minimums and maximums.

This is what I tried.

First, I tested the interior of $K$. Since I got the contradiction ($x=0 $ and $x=-1$), there is none.

Then, Lagrange: $F(x,y,z)=xe^{x+2y+3z}- \lambda (x+2y+3z-16)$.

$F'_{x}=0$ if $(1+x)e^{x+2y+3z}=\lambda$

$F'_{y}=F'_{z}=0$ if $xe^{x+2y+3z}=\lambda$.

I can't solve this system, where did I go wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I have two questions: 1. How do you use Lagrange multipliers when the given conditions are inequalities? 2. Where did the $-6$ come from?

Comment: Edited, it's 16.
I used it since I proved that there are no extremes on the interior, so I tried the boundry: $x+2y+3z=16$.

Comment: I get it now, sorry, you checked the interior. Never mind. But don't forget about the rest of the boundary, when some of the variables is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use any calculus to solve this problem. Since the exponential function is strictly increasing, the largest value it can take on the constraint set is $e^{16}$. To maximize $f$, set $x=16$ and $y=z=0$. To minimize the function, since the exponential function is always positive and one constraint is that $x\geq 0$, the smallest $f$ can be is zero (when $x=0$ and $y$ and $z$ are such that the other constraints are satisfied).

Where your attempt at a solution goes wrong is that at least some of the nonnegativity constraints are binding at the maximum and the minimum.

Comment: Wow, good thinking. 

But, I have to ask you this, is there any way to find the extremes using Lagrange multipliers and other stuff? 

Thank you so much

Comment: You can, with a slight modification. You can use the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions. See the answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747435/correct-formulation-of-equality-and-non-negativity-constrained-non-linear-minimi (Note it involves an equality constraint and some nonnegativity constraints, but the method can also be used when you have only inequality constraints.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $$f(x,y,z)=xe^{x+2y+3z}$$

it is given that $x,y,z$ are non-negative

You know that $e^{x+2y+3z}$ is always greater than 0

thus the minimum it can take is 0

Which is at $x=0$

Similarly You can solve for maximum